# Picklist population from design resource in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I am populate a pick list value from design resource.But it is not loading value in the picklist.
**component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="Recordtype" type="String" access="global"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<ui:Inputselect aura:id="Recordty" value="{!v.Recordt}"/><br/>
```

**Controller js:**

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts = [];
            var inputsel = component.find("Recordty");
            var recur = component.get("v.Recordtype");
            for(var i=0;i<recur.length;i++){
            opts.push({"class": "optionClass", label: recur[i], value:recur[i]});
        }
        inputsel.set("v.Recordt", opts);
    }
```

**Design resource:**

```
<design:component>
<design:attribute name="Recordtype" datasource="Account,Contact,Lead,Opportunity"/> 
</design:component>
```

Comment: I have checked this.But What I am trying from design attribute.Not on the schema

Comment: You've missed the point, then. To set the options of a picklist, you always use v.options, not v.Recordt or some other attribute.

Comment: Even I modify that and changed to this line  var recur = component.find("Recordtype").get("v.value");

Comment: recur is coming as undefined even though I set up values in the design resource.

Comment: Okay, let's back up a second. What's the purpose of what you're trying to do? I have a feeling you're barking up the wrong tree entirely.

Comment: I am trying to see whether I can take string pick list value i have 4 or 5 static string drop down in the component  rather than using more option tags  Thought of maintaining in design resource and pulling it from there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Configure Components for Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm) for what a design resource is:

> Include a design resource in the component bundle to make your Lightning component usable in Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder. Use a design resource to control which attributes are exposed to the Lightning App Builder. A design resource lives in the same folder as your .cmp resource, and describes the design-time behavior of the Lightning component—information that visual tools need to allow adding the component to a page or app.

You use the Design resource to expose checkboxs, input fields, and dropdown lists in the Lightning App Builder so that a non-developer can tweak the settings of the component using the UI. You're not intended, as a programmer, to interact with design:attributes directly. This file is simply a tool to provide hints to Lightning Pages and the Lightning App Builder.

For example, let's say you want to restrict access to the component so that it can only be placed on Lightning Pages that use contacts or leads. You can add sfdc:object elements to limit the component to just two objects:

```
<design:component label="Send an Email">
    <sfdc:objects>
        <sfdc:object>Contact</sfdc:object>
        <sfdc:object>Lead</sfdc:object>
    </sfdc:objects>
</design:component>
```

Or, let's say that you want to let users choose a color scheme, you might do something like this:

```
<design:component label="Event Planner">
    <design:attribute name="ColorTheme" label="Color Theme" datasource="Dark,Light" default="Dark" />
</design:component>
```

As you can see, these are features that expose configuration choices to designers.

So, you *could* use design:attribute to allow an administrator to determine which values appear in your pick list, but this doesn't give you any default values. Instead, consider using the aura:attribute's default value setting if you really wanted to make a list:

```
<aura:attribute name="recordTypeOptions" value="String[]"
                default="['Account','Contact','Lead','Opportunity']" />
```

Which you could then render in your code:

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts = component.get("v.recordTypeOptions").map(function (value) {
        return { "class": "optionClass", "label": value, "value": value };
    });
    component.find("Recordty").set("v.options", opts)
}
```

Comment: A more recent option is to use the `VisualEditor.DynamicPicklist` interface and you can set your datasource as follows: `datasource="apex://MyCustomPickList"`.  See the [Lightning Aura Components Developer Guide: Create Dynamic Picklists for Custom Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_dynamic_picklists.htm) for an example